# Why mini-batch output to Mobilenet is different from single output?

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to check if the mini-batch output is equal to giving all the elements of the mini-batch one by one for evaluating the feature vector of Mobilenet.

Look at the following code:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    (
        hub.KerasLayer("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/mobilenet_v2/feature_vector/4", 
            output_shape=[1280],
            trainable=False
        ),
    )
)

images =  tf.random.uniform(shape=(20, 224, 224, 3))
features = model.predict(images)

for i in range(20):
    image = tf.reshape(images[i, ...], (1, 224, 224, 3))
    image_feature = model.predict(image)

    self.assertTrue((image_feature == features[i, ...]).all())
```

The assertTrue fails in my test. Should not it give the same feature vector for all the images whether they are feed as a mini-batch or one by one?

Comment: Results should be the same, but not necessarily to the last bit. (This is numerical computation optimized for speed on the fly.) How large of a difference are you seeing? For investigation, try code like `np.max(np.abs(... - ...))`. For writing an actual unit test, check out `np.allclose()` or `np.testing.assert_allclose()` with their arguments `atol` and `rtol`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that they are not that much different. In fact they are not bigger than 10e-4. So that is the reason thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has something to do with what means and variances (of BN layers) the model is using. If the moving means and variances from the training stage are used (and they should be, IMO), the single outputs should be exactly the same with the minibatch output. Difference <= 10e-4 is still large enough to give inconsistent predictions.

Comment: Are you suggesting that this behavior is a bug?

Comment: To be frank, I don't know. However, following arnoegw's comments to your question, I don't think any optimization algorithms should alter the predictions, even on the scale of 1e-3 like you said.

Comment: I believe this behavior is a bug.  Everything should be fixed at test time and independent of batch size.